# Rails usage of .from()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

In a typical blog app if i do something like:

```
p = Post.order('created_at DESC').limit(10)
p.from(5)
```

It raises:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: near "5": syntax error: SELECT  "posts".* FROM 5  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 10
```

I'm trying to get the first five posts in an array and the five next in another array. If i use the .from() on an array it's working fine, i get the elements i want beginning from the number i selected. But if i use the .from() in a view or in a controller it will try to generate a new query instead of apply the .from() on the object/array.

My controller was doing:

```
@last_ten_posts = Post.order('created_at DESC').limit(10)
```

And the view:

```
@last_ten_posts.first(5).each do |post|
@last_ten_posts.from(5).each do |post|
```

How should i use the .from() method ?

Thanks

EDIT: @Rubyist give remember me the first way i was dealing with the posts, i'm interesting in finding why the .from() doesn't work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The from method doesn't work because it used to specify which table the records will be fetched, so in your original query, you are looking for posts from table 5, which doesn't make sense since you don't have a table 5, you have a table called posts not 5.

More information on the from method - http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-from

You might want to use a different method like offset - http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-offset

```
first_five = Post.order('created_at DESC').limit(5)
last_five = Post.offset(5).order('created_at DESC').limit(5)
```

Comment: Thanks, the offset() seems a good way i'm testing it right now! The from() method in the api is also use to select in an array. How the difference is maid ?  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#method-i-from

Answer (score 1):

```
@last_ten_posts = Post.order('created_at DESC').limit(10)
first_five = @last_ten_posts.first(5)
last_five = @last_ten_posts.last(5)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I've already try that, i don't know why i wanna use the from() method. I'll check again.

Comment: Yes it's working, i remember why i avoid this way: if i have less than 10 posts i will show same posts in the two array. I have to write something to check if the post isn't in the first 5. Thats, why i used .from(). ( I have an if statement like : if posts.count > 5 do posts.from(5).limit(5) ). Any idea for the .from() method ?